# Email Javascript Validation Message

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, email

I would like a message to be shown to the user, if an email address is entered incorrectly.

Html

```
<p>Email: <input type="email" id="email" onblur="validateEmail()" 
required>

<p id="emailMessage"></p>
```

Javascript

```
function validateEmail(email){
    var regEx = /\S+@\S+/;
    var result = regEX.test(email);

    if (result = true)
        document.getElementById("emailMessage").innerhtml = ""
    else (result = false)
        document.getElementById("emailMessage").innerhtml = "Please enter a valid 
email address"
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to validate an email address in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/how-to-validate-an-email-address-in-javascript)

Comment: try if (result). What you are doing is making result equal to true .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many issues in your approach. Because you seems to be new to this, I will tell you what is wrong step-by-step:

- `result = true` and `result = false` will set the value of result to a boolean. A condition has to be `==` or `===`. Or in your case, just use the `result` variable, what is already an boolean because of the result of `.test()`.
- Use `innerHTML` instead of `innerhtml`.
- It's not allowed to break a string in javascript like this.
- Your variable is called `regEx` not `regEX`.
- `email` is not a parameter of the function by default, you need to pass `this` to the function to have it available.
- You need to check on `email.value`, nut just `email`, beacuse this is just the element.
- `else` can't have a condition to check, if you want to you need to use `else if`, but that is not needed here.

```js
function validateEmail(email) {
  var regEx = /\S+@\S+/;
  var result = regEx.test(email.value);

  if (result) {
    document.getElementById("emailMessage").innerHTML = "";
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById("emailMessage").innerHTML = "Please enter a valid email address";
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Email:</p>
<input type="email" id="email" onblur="validateEmail(this)" required>
<p id="emailMessage"></p>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
//correct code
  function validateEmail(email)
     {
      var regEx = /\S+@\S+/;
      var result = regEX.test(email);
      if (result == true)
          document.getElementById("emailMessage").innerHTML = ""
      else (result == false)
          document.getElementById("emailMessage").innerHTML = "Please enter a valid email address"
}
```

Comment: While this may answer the question it's better to add some description on how this answer may help to solve the issue. Please read [_How do I write a good answer_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) to know more.

Answer (score -3):

```
document.getElementById("emailMessage").innerHTML = "Please enter a valid 
email address"
```

//use innerHTML not innerhtml, that is the problem

Comment: There are even more issues in his code. Not even this. This answer is just not helpful ...

Comment: No, you didn't. You posted a new answer. And the new answer is still completely invalid.

Comment: Please test you code by yourself and see if it will work. Spoiler: it woun't.

Comment: Do you even know what _spoiler_ means, in this context? ;) It mean some kind of a hint, nothing rude here. And in your context, it would mean that I am a _spoiler_, not you. ;) And it has nothing to do with the fact, if I posted the question or not. Your both answers are simply incorrect will not work in any way. If you would put more effort in your answers you will probably see it by yourself. I'm not sure why your would rather _ignore_ me, because I'm not the creator, instead of fixing your answers ... I'm out now, your choice.